# What is the need for finding the equilibrium points in the mathematical models?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, biology

What is the need for finding the equilibrium points in the mathematical models?
Why we check the stability of those equilibrium points?What benefit we will get in real life after doing such calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of equilibrium of a *dynamical system* is associated with the attractors of the system, which characterise the long-term behaviour

Any dynamical system may have no, one or several equilibrium points, each of which
may either be stable or unstable. A plain mechanical example is a simple pendulum. If
the pendulum is at the downward position, the system will remain there forever, and
thus, the downward position is an equilibrium point. Obviously, this equilibrium is
stable (if friction is considered). Likewise, it is easy to see that the upward position is an unstable equilibrium.

Understanding these equilibria tells you important system behaviours that characterise the model. Understanding these, leads one to understand the model fully.

Comment: and what is the benefit of doing stability analysis? for eg if someone is working on the disease model and finds stability of  the equilibrium points,why does he do so?why does he check the stability?

Comment: @ParagGupta Stability analysis of equilibria is necessary and important for non-linear models that underpin such topics as disease modelling as the equilibria need not be *global*. f the equilibrium points can be categorised under a systematic approach, such as first and second Lyapunov criteria.

Comment: Thanks Kelvin.Could you please suggest me a good book from where I can learn about the equilibrium points and their stability analysis ?

Comment: @ParagGupta No problem at all Parag; you could try this book, it isn't cheap but is well worth the price.It considers the Lyapunov stability theory in great detail. https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319271996